# How can I replace a light fixture with a two way switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have just replaced an old florescent fixture with a new incandescent fixture.  Wired according to directions.  Light comes on and does not throw the breaker so I know I have it wired correctly, however, the switch now will not turn the light off.  It is a two way light switch and neither one now works.  Any suggestions for solving this problem?

Comment: You did not wire it correctly.  Let us know what wires you have available.  It sounds like that you wired all of the blacks together though which will keep your light on all the time.

Comment: I have to agree with @DMoore, just because it doesn't pop the breaker doesn't mean it's wired correctly.

Comment: Ok.  I have tried each black wire separately wiring it in one at a time with the neutral line.  Only one of them will work when wired into the neutral line, but the light still continues to stay on all the time with the switch not working.  There is one white/neutral line that was originally wired in with the black on the old fixture.  It remains with the black/hot line or else the light does not come on.  So right now I have all the blacks together with the one white and all the whites together.  ??

Comment: Your current configuration will definitely keep the light powered at all times.  So you have the light.  Tell us exactly what wires (black/white/red?) are coming in from each direction and where they are going or came from.  How many switches do you have?

Comment: You should wire the new fixture **exactly** as the old fixture was wired.

Comment: @Tester101 That ship may have sailed. This is a great argument to snap a picture(s) of the existing wiring with a cell phone before a single disconnect is done.

Comment: @bib Probably. Never understood why people just start ripping stuff apart, or why they think trial and error electrical work is a good idea.

Comment: @Tester101 One of the biggest issues on a relatively easy job is the failure to properly mark a white wire acting as a switched hot. Pre disassembly connections will usually reveal, but once they are all free ...